# How can I include model ancestor property display names in validation error messages?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, validation

- In ASP.NET Core MVC (and ASP.NET MVC too), the `Html.ValidationSummary` helper extension and the `<div asp-validation-summary="">` tag-helper both only render the "short" Display Name of the invalid property.
- This means that if a form/`@model` has sub-forms (all using the same sub-form class) with the same validation errors then the user sees unhelpfully ambiguous validation error messages in the summary.
- For example, consider this (contrived) form class below:

```cs
public class NewCompanyAccountForm
{
    [Display( Name = "Primary user" )]
    public NewUserForm PrimaryUser { get; } = new NewUserForm();

    [Display( Name = "Secondary user" )]
    public NewUserForm SecondaryUser { get; } = new NewUserForm();

    [Display( Name = "Tertiary user" )]
    public NewUserForm TertiaryUser { get; } = new NewUserForm();
}

public class NewUserForm
{
    [Required]
    [Display( Name = "User name" )]
    [RegularExpression( "^[a-z][0-9_a-z]+$" )]
    [StringLength( 20 )]
    public String? UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display( Name = "Display name" )]
    [StringLength( 50 )]
    public String? DisplayName { get; set; }
}
```

And these views:

**NewCompanyAccount.cshtml**:

```razor
@model NewCompanyAccountForm

<div asp-validation-summary="All"></div>

<fieldset>
    <legend>@Html.DisplayNameFor( m => m.PrimaryUser )</legend>
    
    <partial name="NewUserForm" for="PrimaryUser"/>

</fieldset>

<fieldset>
    <legend>@Html.DisplayNameFor( m => m.SecondaryUser )</legend>
    
    <partial name="NewUserForm" for="SecondaryUser"/>

</fieldset>

<fieldset>
    <legend>@Html.DisplayNameFor( m => m.TertiaryUser )</legend>
    
    <partial name="NewUserForm" for="TertiaryUser "/>

</fieldset>
```

**NewUserForm.cshtml**:

```razor
@model NewUserForm

<div class="field">
    @Html.LabelFor( m => m.UserName )
    @Html.TextBoxFor( m => m.UserName )
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor( m => m.UserName )
</div>

<div class="field">
    @Html.LabelFor( m => m.DisplayName )
    @Html.TextBoxFor( m => m.DisplayName )
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor( m => m.DisplayName )
</div>
```

---

If someone submits an empty form, then the `<div asp-validation-summary="All"></div>` will render a list that looks like this:

```html
<ul>
    <li>The User name field is required</li>
    <li>The Display name field is required</li>
    <li>The User name field is required</li>
    <li>The Display name field is required</li>
    <li>The User name field is required</li>
    <li>The Display name field is required</li>
</ul>
```

What I want is the validation summary to include the `[Display( Name = "" )]` of the parent form/model property for all ancestors going back up to the form/model root.

...so the user would see something like this:

```html
<ul>
    <li>The Primary User's User name field is required</li>
    <li>The Primary User's Display name field is required</li>
    <li>The Secondary User's User name field is required</li>
    <li>The Secondary User's Display name field is required</li>
    <li>The Tertiary User's User name field is required</li>
    <li>The Tertiary User's Display name field is required</li>
</ul>
```

I can't see any obvious method or functionality built-in to ASP.NET MVC or ASP.NET Core for this - which is odd because functionality like this would be essential for forms using `List<ChildForm>`, for example.

Answer (score 1):

I tried as below:

NewCompanyAccount.cshtml:

```
@model NewCompanyAccountForm
@{  
    ViewDataDictionary PrimaryUserViewData = new ViewDataDictionary(this.ViewData);
    PrimaryUserViewData.Add("WhichUser", "PrimaryUser");
    ViewDataDictionary SecondaryUserViewData = new ViewDataDictionary(this.ViewData);
    SecondaryUserViewData.Add("WhichUser", "SecondaryUser");
    ViewDataDictionary TertiaryUserViewData = new ViewDataDictionary(this.ViewData);
    TertiaryUserViewData.Add("WhichUser", "TertiaryUser");
}

<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Test">
 
    <fieldset>
        <legend>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.PrimaryUser)</legend>

        <partial name="NewUserForm" for="PrimaryUser" view-data="PrimaryUserViewData"/>

    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.SecondaryUser)</legend>

        <partial name="NewUserForm" for="SecondaryUser" view-data="SecondaryUserViewData"/>

    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.SecondaryUser)</legend>

        <partial name="NewUserForm" for="TertiaryUser " view-data="TertiaryUserViewData"/>
        

    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<style>
        .field-validation-valid {
            display: none;
        }
    
        .validation-summary-valid {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
```

pratial view:

```
@model NewUserForm
@{
    var message = ViewData.ContainsKey("WhichUser") ? ViewData["WhichUser"].ToString() : "";    
    var usernamessage = string.Format("{0}'s User name field is required", message);
    var displaynamessage = string.Format("{0}'s DisPlay name field is required", message);
}


<div class="field">

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName, usernamessage)
</div>

<div class="field">

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.DisplayName)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DisplayName)

    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.DisplayName, displaynamessage)
</div>
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Interesting approach!  (+1) - I never thought of doing it this way: I was thinking of iterating over property navigation paths in `ModelExpresssion` and repeatedly getting `DisplayNameFor`. I'll try your approach out later this week (I'm on a different project right now)

Comment: ...that said, can you show it working with `Html.ValidationSummary()` or `<div asp-validation-summary="All"></div>` ?